# Best Practice in Adonis.js: User hasOne Role or Role hasMany Users?

Tags: node.js, laravel, adonis.js

I'm working on an application in Adonis.js, and I'm designing the database structure. In this application, a user can be associated with a specific role (like 'admin,' 'user,' etc.) that determines their permissions and access levels.

I'm wondering what the best practice is for modeling this relationship in Adonis.js. Should I use User hasOne Role or Role hasMany Users?

What's the best approach in Adonis.js for this kind of relationship, considering flexibility and maintainability? I'd appreciate any insights or advice on the topic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Adonis.js, the choice of whether to use "User hasOne Role" or "Role hasMany Users" for modeling the relationship between users and roles largely depends on your application's requirements and the level of flexibility and maintainability you desire. Both approaches are valid, and the choice should be made based on your specific use case. Let's explore both options:

User hasOne Role:

In this approach, each user has a single role associated with them.
It's a good choice if your application enforces a strict "one user, one role" relationship.
Provides a clear and simple way to assign and manage roles for individual users.

Role hasMany Users:

In this approach, each role can have multiple users associated with it.
It's a more flexible approach if your application needs to support scenarios where multiple users share the same role.
Allows for more dynamic role management, as you can easily add or remove users from a role without changing the user's structure.